# In British English, should it be "licensee" or "licencee"?

Tags: nouns, british-english, orthography

We all know that "license" in American English is "licence" in British English.  But what about the person to whom the licence is given?

Various dictionaries show the 'c' version, e.g.:

- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/licencee)

Additionally, I can see other resources in my own country using this spelling, e.g.:

- [Centennial Parklands](https://www.centennialparklands.com.au/venue-hire/outdoor-public-events/toolkit/glossary)

But managers in my own company (in Australia) claim to have done "a lot of research" on the subject and decided to use the 's' version.  This seems wrong to me, but I would like a better answer to the question before I decide whether to request a change or just change our spell checking to allow their spelling.

Comment: I strenuously object to the licentious nature of this question!

Comment: licensing agreement + licensee and licensor, pretty standard. This is all pretty standard and your managers are right. //https://www.autm.net/AUTMMain/media/.../V4/TTP_V4_AnatomyLicense.pdf

Comment: In British English licence is the correct spelling for the noun, and is also an acceptable variant spelling of the verb. US English allows both spellings for both noun and verb.
https://www.englishforums.com/English/LicenceAgreementLicenseAgreement/bbvpdr/post.htm

Comment: @Lambie No, it's not an acceptable variant spelling for the verb. [*Licence* is a noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/licence). The verb is spelled with an *s* and so *licensee* and *licensor* are too. *Licencor* makes no sense. (The fact that people misuse *licencee* doesn't make it right or acceptable.)

Comment: Please do not impute usages to me I did not use. Of course, it's licensee and licensor. In British English, licence (noun) and license (verb). See this IP (intellectual property) from an official British government site: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/licensing-intellectual-property Intellectual property can be bought, sold or licensed. I have been editing legal texts for a long, long time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously, in American English one would expect to see something like the [following](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licensee,licencee&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3):

[image]

What is not so obvious is that British English has a [similar graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licensee,licencee&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3) on these words:

[image]

To prove that these graphs are reliable (at least reliable enough for this answer), graphs of American and British English on *license* vs. *licence* follow:

[American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=license,licence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3):

[image]

[British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=license,licence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3):

[image]

This ties in with what we already know about British vs. American preferences about the word *licence/license*. And to a degree it proves a point about *licensee* vs. *licencee*. It seems certain that *licensee* is the preferred spelling in either corpus.

And I'm terribly sorry for the gargantuan scale of this answer, but I thought the graphs would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using either 's' or 'c' to match the spelling of the **verb** in whichever variety of English you're writing in, on the basis that the **-ee** ending is generally used to derive a noun from the verb, not the noun.

(Cf. *train/training* -> *trainee*, not **trainingee*, or *evacute/evacuation* -> *evacuee*, not **evacuationee*)

Comment: Isn't it *evacuatee*? Although I see my browser marks that as misspelled, but doesn't object to *evacuee*...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is evacuee.  [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=evacuee), [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evacuee), they seem to agree.

Comment: I can't say I've ever heard "evacuatee", and Googling it seems to bring up some silly music thing. However, I think it's immaterial to the point I was making.

Comment: Drat, I thought it might come to the choice of verb.  It sounds like management want to use "licence" for nouns and "license" for verbs.  I am used to using "licence" for both.

Comment: OK, the usage you mention that your management want to adopt is conventional UK usage; the usage you want to adopt is conventional US usage. I'd say bang your heads together and decide whether you want UK or US usage...

Comment: +1 Isn't the spelling of the verb always _license_? I thought it was only the noun that changed spelling (_licence_ in BrE and _license_ in AmE). See also _licensee_ in the [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/licensee) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/licensee).

Comment: My observation (mainly from translating and using contracts in day-to-day life, not because I've specifically researched this point) is that US usage tends to use a single spelling everywhere, whereas UK usage tends to make the "licence"/"license" distinction for noun vs verb. I don't think it matters too much: US people use UK contracts and vice versa. Just pick a convention you like and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such word, "licencee".

*Licence* = noun; the licence document.
*License* = verb; i.e. to grant licence.
*Licensee* = the holder of the licence.

The Americans don't like the noun/verb distinction and just use *license* for both.
However, *licencee* has never been a word.

Comment: Licensee and licensor do exist.